# jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut - swapping divs

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I'm new to jQuery and javascript in general but am plugging my way through thanks to sites like these.

I have a page with six hidden divs that are called with corresponding links with individual ids. When each div is made visable (.fadeIn), the currently displayed div is hidden (.fadeOut).

It all works fine but my code seems to be really long and ungainly.
Is there an easier, shorter, less code-intensive way to perform the same task please?

Here is my js:

Many thanks in advance.
Mike

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#link1").click(function() {
$("#panel2").fadeOut("slow", function() {                       
$("#panel3").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel4").fadeOut("slow", function() {                       
$("#panel5").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel6").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel1").fadeIn("slow")});
});
});
});
});
});

$("#link2").click(function() {
    $("#panel1").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel3").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel4").fadeOut("slow", function() {                       
$("#panel5").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel6").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel2").fadeIn("slow")});
});
});
});
});
});

$("#link3").click(function() {
    $("#panel1").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel2").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel4").fadeOut("slow", function() {                       
$("#panel5").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel6").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel3").fadeIn("slow")});
});
});
});
});
});

$("#link4").click(function() {
    $("#panel1").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel2").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel3").fadeOut("slow", function() {                       
$("#panel5").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel6").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel4").fadeIn("slow")});
});
});
});
});
});

$("#link5").click(function() {
    $("#panel1").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel2").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel3").fadeOut("slow", function() {                       
$("#panel4").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel6").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel5").fadeIn("slow")});
});
});
});
});
});

$("#link6").click(function() {
    $("#panel1").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel2").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel3").fadeOut("slow", function() {                       
$("#panel4").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel5").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel6").fadeIn("slow")});
});
});
});
});
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code could certainly be made more efficient and flexible, but for a simple 6 element example as the above it should be enough.  This was mostly done as just a proof of concept.

I chose to add the classes programmatically, but ideally you should have the classes added in the HTML.  If it were me I would probably also have used expandos instead of id string replacement.

EDIT, fixes added:
Recursive function for sequential animation makes sure that fadeIn is processed at the right time.  There may be a more efficient method for this, such as using a counter, but for just 6 elements it should be fine, and this matches your original code more faithfully.
Fix for animations processing at incorrect times, such as when you click many links simultaneously, causing multiple panels to try to fadeIn, by stopping and finishing animations.

```
jQuery(function($){
    //add links/panels class to all elements whose id begins with link/panel
    $("[id^=link]").addClass("links");
    $("[id^=panel]").addClass("panels");

    $(".links").click(function(e){
        //find all panels, make a normal array, and stop/finish all animations
        var panels=$.makeArray($(".panels").stop(true, true));

        //find panel to show
        var panelShow=$("#"+this.id.replace("link","panel"));

        //recursive function to execute fades in sequence
        function queueFX(queue){
            if(queue.length==0){
                panelShow.fadeIn("slow");
                return;
            }
            $(queue.shift()).fadeOut("slow", function(){
                queueFX(queue);
            });
        }
        queueFX(panels);

        //stop event propogation and default behavior, commented out because you don't seem to want this behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        //e.stopPropagation();
        //return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a million for this.  However my links stop working with this in place.  I have six uniquely id'd links with href="#" tags.  Should I be using something different?

Comment: That's odd.  I tested it myself on the page you provided and it seems to work okay for me.  You can modify "return false" if you want.  I added that so that it doesn't try to navigate the link.  May not be what you intended

Comment: Commented out the return false and explained it, as well as adding fixes so the animations behave as you most likely intend it to.

Comment: Really wish I understood this as you're all being so helpful. My links still don't work using this code. Think I'm going to have to take a course in "not being a pain in the backside". :o)

Comment: Hi, it's fine.  It's nice to have some script hacks to flex my script-fu :p  Can you explain in more detail what you mean by your links don't work?  Do you mean fading doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for being so understanding. Yes, clicking links doesn't fadeOut visible panel or fadeIn the panel for the corresponding link. It's like it's dead. I've uploaded the page with your script in it to www.miketest.tk so you can see it. I also realised that I had the 6 panels styled with a class which I've now changed to seperate id's (which I'll want anyway as I'm going to use different background images on each panel). I wondered if that was conflicting with the class that you created in your script?

Comment: I see now what went wrong, you didn't use the document ready event with this code.  You still need to enclose it in the ready event, I'll add the code just to make it clear.
All the elements are allowed to have multiple classes.  eg: <div class="class1 class2 class3 class4"></div> can be referred to as $("div.class1") or $(".class2") or $(".class3") ...

Comment: Enclosed in document ready event now.  Should work as is now.

Comment: I really shouldn't be allowed out on my own! Highly embarrassed at my ignorance and supremely grateful for your persistence and explanations. I'm always astonished at how sites like this work and how happy people are to help complete strangers with their problems. If only the world were run by geeks instead of politicians it would be a hell of a place to live! Many, many thanks. Mike

Answer (score 2):

Having your ids it might be like this:

```
$.each([1,2,3,4,5,6], function(_, index) {
    $('#link' + index).click(function() {
        $('[id^=panel]').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('#panel' + index).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("a[id^='link']").click(function() {
      $("div[id^='panel']").fadeOut("slow");
      $("div#"+this.id.replace('link', 'panel')).fadeIn("slow");
   });
});
```

Comment: This will fade out all panels simultaneously, not in sequence like the original code.  You can use a recursive function or fxQueues plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/fxqueues.

Comment: @user120242 : if i use each(), then.

Comment: It still won't.  The queues are attached by div.  Also, that throws an error.

Comment: After re-reading the OP, I realized that the OP likely did not actually intend for them to fade sequentially.  Seems that he might have done that unintentionally.

Comment: It was all completely unintentional.  I just used something that (with my limited knowledge) worked ok.  No need for sequential fadeOut, just want all divs closed except the one I have clicked the link for.

Comment: Apologies for this chaps but my links don't work at all using the code above and I'm getting a syntax error on line 5.  My links are simple href="#" with id's of "link1" to "link6".  Should I be doing something different?
I love the simplicity of the code above and from my limited understanding it makes sense.

Comment: @Mike Turbutt : please check now

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, that code is functioning now but it only fades out the div that is currently "display:block" (in this case id="panel1" on pageload). It doesn't fade in the hidden div from the corresponding selected link.
If it would help to see it, I've the page on a test server at www.miketest.tk
Thanks again.

Comment: That does indeed work Gaurav, and it's so simple too.  There is one small issue (that can probably be fixed with a delay or something) but the div doesn't fadeout before the new div fades in. So it displaces till the other one is gone. Could I add line 5 as a callback on line 4 so it won't run till finished?  Blimey, I almost sound like I know what I'm talking about! :o)

Comment: Sorted! Just wanted to say a big thank you to everyone who commented and tried to help me out. What you guys do and the way that you do it is amazing and inspiring. Hope I can be of use to someone in the future. Mike

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Toggle lets you the animation for one

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

As for truely Shortening the code I would use a class identifier for your panels.

Identify panel groups like

```
$("#panel3").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel4").fadeOut("slow", function() {                       
$("#panel5").fadeOut("slow", function() {
$("#panel6").fadeOut("slow", function() {
```

and then assign the associated HTML elements a class like

Your jQuery can  now be `$(".panelGroup1").fadeOut...`

The . class selector for jQuery and the # is the id Selector.

Check out selectors and you can do a bunch of other crazy things

http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=Selector&go=

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'll check it out. As far as js goes, I'm really a noob and have much to learn.  Hence the huge code above. :o)

Comment: I just went through all this last year. It is places like stack overflow that saved my butt from hours of browsing the jquery api site.

Comment: I still find the generosity of people like you guys, with your time and knowlege, amazing. Thanks a million for offering your help. I'm learning loads. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good solutions, I have a general comment:

It seems a bit unnecessary for each panel to have a unique id. You might have a perfect reason to do so, but wouldn't it be enough to group your panels with a class selector? This would make your overall code, as well as your jquery, much simpler and easier to maintain.

Comment: Each panel has a unique background called in CSS to suit the content on that panel. That's the only reason really.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
function fadeElementIn(fadedElement) {
    $("[id^=panel]").fadeOut("slow");
    $(fadedElement).fadeIn("slow");
}
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#link1").click(fadeElementIn($("#panel1")));
    $("#link2").click(fadeElementIn($("#panel2")));
    $("#link3").click(fadeElementIn($("#panel3")));
    $("#link4").click(fadeElementIn($("#panel4")));
}
```

remember to adjust your elements positioning if you want the one that's fading out and the one that's fading in to occupy the same space

cheers

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. Why the need to adjust positioning? 
Could I add the second part of the function as a callback?  That way, the fadedOut element would be display:none in CSS before the fadedIn element appeared.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: oh, yeah, you can surely do that, I just pictured it sort of "morphing" from one to the other (i.e. old one fades out while the new one is fading in on top of it). But yeah, you can totally do that.

Comment: I'm finally sorted. Thanks a million for your time and expertise. This site (and you guys) are amazing. I wish the guy who fixes my car was as generous. :o)  Cheers