# how to fadeIn and fadeOut All Element in div (jquery)

Tags: jquery, gallery

how to fadeIn and fadeOut img tags in div use Jquery

```
sample:

<div class='myDivgallery' >
<img style="display: none;" src="images/1.jpg" />
<img style="display: none;" src="images/2.jpg" />
<img style="display: none;" src="images/3.jpg" />
<img style="display: none;" src="images/4.jpg" />
</div>
```

i have to make a slideGallery , but , i do not use plugin .

thank

Comment: On what event? Page load? Hover?

Comment: setInterval for all time

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut - swapping divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571110/jquery-fadein-and-fadeout-swapping-divs)

Comment: @erfan ... c'mon ( you mean setTimeout! ) ;-)

Comment: yes roXon , i have give time use fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erfan ... if you want a SLIDE gallery than : [SLIDE GALLERY](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/MSNJh/)

If you want what you want ( ;D ) than try:

**EDIT**
Due to errors caused by a well known jQuery ticket I came up with this demo:

### [SIMPLE FADE GALLERY](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/CyQcH/1/)

```
var el = $('.myDivgallery img');
var z = 1;
$(el[0]).show();
function loop(ev) {
    el.siblings().delay(1000).fadeOut(300).eq(z).fadeIn(500, function() {
        check = z != el.length-1 ? z++ : z=0;
        loop();         
    });
}
loop();
```

(Thanks to the community for not cooking me a *maccaroni pasta al pesto* for my previous demo :D )
(And don't ask me why I called a var "`z`" that actually do some `c`ounts)

---

**The old version created animations buildups on page/tab absence** 
(I leave it here just for 'bad practice / example' .)

### [ERRATA fade gallery](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/CyQcH/)

```
$('.myDivgallery img:eq(0)').show(); // show first image on page load

var imgC = 0;   // set counter to '0'

function fade() {   // introduce our function

    var img = $('.myDivgallery img');
    var imgL = img.length;    // get the number of images

    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        imgC++;      // count +1
        img.eq(imgC-1).fadeIn().siblings('img').fadeOut();
        if ( imgC >= imgL){ // if counter goes over our number of images...
            imgC = 0;       // reset the counter to '0'
        }
        fade();             // run our function in a loop
    }, 2000);               // timeout delay

}
fade();                     // start our function
```

**read again... B. A. D. ...! bad bad bad**

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.myDivgallery img').fadeIn('slow'); // fade in 

$('.myDivgallery img').fadeOut('slow'); // fade out
```

Comment: fadeIn and FadeOut for all images !

Comment: @efran you need to review jquery selectors, the above code will do exactly what you asked for, it will fadeIn/fadeOut all image tags within any element of the myDivgallery css class, which is the case for your container DIV element.

Comment: "fadeOut all img tags in div" please edit your question if you wish to select all images. Also reading the documentation wouldn't hurt, this is very basic JQuery.

Comment: -1 untill if you don't change your answer. people c'mon! Think! (Coder... this will implicate ALL images in the DOM)

Comment: roxon, i understand that. Hence, initially i had it select all images inside the div. I think erfan would need to understand the implication of selecting all images.