# fadein/fadeout issue, tried stop but does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

So all I want to do is fade out a div and fade in another. When i hover a link i want to fadeout prev div and fade in the proper div. everything works fine unless I hover over the links too fast. when i hover too fast, a div would not get faded out. I have tried using stop(), and tried different combinations of true false on the stop function but nothing works. if i change the fade timer to 0 then it works. the code I have is too much to pasted here but basically it is not a simple fadein/fadeout. I have some other stuff going on before the fade function is called

here is my fade function

```
var fadeEffect = function (a, b) {
    $(a).fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(b).fadeIn(300);
    });
}
```

it's a private function inside of an object. I tried using stop() on a and/or b and i still get the same thing. If i change the 300 to 0, it works fine
anyone have any ideas?

simplified version here http://jsfiddle.net/LLMUX/9/

Comment: Can you please add your HTML or even better create a http://jsfiddle.net/ thanks

Comment: added fiddle, that is a great tool thanks for sharing it

Comment: you've tried `stop(true, true)`? `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` will save the current opacity when the animation begins.

Comment: tried it but it does not work, please see the fiddle link, the code is complicated but as long as the fade timers are at 0 it works fine but if it is not at 0 then the issue occurs

Comment: Check out the answer to this question - i think its what you need ? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571110/jquery-fadein-and-fadeout-swapping-divs

Comment: I looked at it but it looks like a rotator only.

Comment: @user1058134 yep sorry - i fully ready your jsfiddle and its a complicated beast compared with that other question - i will have another look ...

Comment: ok thanks, it might look more complicated than it is. I think the basic problem is the fadeout is not done or something and another fade is called then something messes up. it only happens if i hover too fast, but if i change the fade timer to 0 it is good so i dunno

Comment: @user1058134 i have added an answer - seems to work for me ...

Comment: yes it has fixed that issue, in my full version of the code i am having the same trouble so i will try your solution on the other divs too, thanks. I have worked so long on this i think this will lead to my code completion, thank you

Comment: @user1058134 you could change the selector of the stop to `$('#parent div")` and this will select all child div elements, like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/LLMUX/12/ makes things easier

Comment: I thought of the usage of this stop so I pasted my full version of the code at http://jsfiddle.net/LLMUX/13/ basically whenever i fade it takes 2 IDs, and I have access to these 2 ids at any time so for my final edit i used the solution you came up with on just the 2 IDs, i put it on them both because this could happen either on the fadein or the fadeout. specially if the fade timer is longer than 300 milliseconds. you have helped me a lot i been stuck on this for the past 2 days, thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your JSFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/LLMUX/11/

What i did was add the stop to the divs that were being animated - that stops the duplicates :

```
   $("#vehicleSelector .vehiclesList").bind({
       mouseenter: function(event) {
          $('#vehicleSlides div, #promoSlides div').stop(true,true); // stop any running animations
           event.stopPropagation();
           sControl.timerIsOn = false;
           showSecondary(this.id)
       },
       mouseleave: function(event) {
           $('#vehicleSlides div, #promoSlides div').stop(true,true); // stop any running animations
           event.stopPropagation();
           next();
       }
   });
```